# Admob placed in bottom of screen in frameLayout

Tags: android, layout, admob

i have this frameLayout with placed adMob

Problem is, that i'm not able to place ad banner in bottom of the screen.

I tried to use inner relative layouts, but without luck.

I would like to use Frame (or scroll) layout if it was possible.

Thanks for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/mainActLayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


<!-- LOGO BACKGROUND -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoBackgroundImg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/lighter_blue"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@color/blue" />

<!-- LOGO -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImgIV"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/appmainlogo" />

<!-- EU FLAG IMG BUTTON -->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/euFlagImgBtn"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/euflag" />

<!-- CAR PLATE ID TEXT INPUT -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/carPlateIdEditText"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:hint="@string/insert_car_plate_number"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:text="8B67354"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submiBtn"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
    android:background="@color/lighter_blue"
    android:onClick="checkSpz"
    android:text="@string/check"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- FIRST ICON -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstIconTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
    android:text="@string/icon_safe"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="80sp" />

<!-- SECOND ICON -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondIconTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
    android:text="@string/icon_quick"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="80sp" />

<!-- THIRD ICON -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/thirdIconTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
    android:text="@string/icon_quality"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="80sp" />

<!-- HEADING TV -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/safeDescTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
    android:text="@string/safe"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quickDescTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
    android:text="@string/quick"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qualityDescTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="470dp"
    android:text="@string/quality"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<!-- LONG DESCRIPTION -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Ověřte\npřed koupí"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Databáze \nonline "
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstTv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Aktuální \ndata"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="16sp" />


  <!-- ADMOB BANNER -->
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6024201770538830/8508221909"
                     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mainActLayout"
                     android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                     android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                     ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 000000000000000"
                     ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>      

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a new `RelativeLayout` and move the `AdView` and align it to `Parent Bottom` and include the other `FrameLayout`

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/other_framelayout"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have all your layouts placed inside another relative layout, that should solve your problem or you can also email admob support with your project, appid, api and sdk and request for integration...